# How to inject subclasses of EJB

Tags: jakarta-ee, dependency-injection, ejb-3.0

I have abstract EJB and two subclasses of it. In my managed bean I want to have a field of abstract type and initialize it depending on parameters passed to the page with instance of either one of the subclasses. I guess there is no way to do this using injection and I should use good old JNDI lookup... Or maybe there is a way to redesign it to be able to use injection?

**Revision** I guess I can't define EJB abstract, but that doesn't change the situation. Even if AbstractEJB is not abstract, I want to instantiate its subclasses only.

```
@Stateless
public abstract class AbstractEJB {
    public abstract void method1();
}

@Stateless
public class Implementation1 extends AbstractEJB () {
    public void method1() { ... }
}

@Stateless
public class Implementation2 extends AbstractEJB () {
    public void method1() { ... }
}

@ManagedBean 
public class MyManagedBean {

    @EJB
    AbstractEJB myEJB; //has to be initialized with either Implementation1 or Implementation2 instance
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This is not how EJBs are intended to be used. You don't inject implementations, but interfaces.

Come up with an interface (you need it in EJB 3.0) and an abstract class (you can have your EJB inherit from an abstract non-EJB class; abstract EJBs have no sense, as they're meant to be instantiated by containers). Use the "name" parameter of respective annotations:

```
public abstract class Abstract implements MyEJBIntf {
    public abstract void method1();
}

@Stateless(name="EJB1") // defaults to "EJB1" anyway
public class EJB1 extends Abstract { ... }

@Stateless
public class EJB2 extends Abstract { ... }

@ManagedBean 
public class MyManagedBean {
    @EJB(name="EJB1") // or "EJB2"
    MyEJBIntf myEJB; 
}
```

Comment: This doesn't fully solve my problem - I need to determine the subclass to instantiate in runtime (depending on parameters the page open with)

Comment: No, it doesn't, I overlooked this assumption. Injections take place at application startup, only JNDI lookup is dynamic. Another option is to inject both EJBs into different fields and having one of them chosen by an "if" or some more elaborate pattern.

Comment: _Another option is to inject both EJBs into different fields and having one of them chosen by an "if" or some more elaborate pattern_ - That's exactly how I currently have this problem solved. I guess I was just trying to avoid costs associated with injection of the unneeded instance.

Comment: >You don't inject implementations, but interfaces. - In EJB 3.1 you can inject implementations, but they have to be concrete non-final classes.

Comment: You should consider creating different interfaces for each subclass

Answer (score -3):

Please check Spring, I think you can found what you need. 
http://www.mkyong.com/spring/how-to-define-bean-properties-in-spring/ 
http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.3/reference/beans.html